# Flutter notification

Tags: flutter, dart, push-notification

I have a flutter application Linked with backend (php/my SQL) ,I need when user add new item in specific page in app send notification to all users . so how can i do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way is to use the Firebase!
Fire base is maintained by Google, just like Flutter and they're being made to work together!

Try the https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_messaging (Firebase Messaging).
It's free in most case scenario, and you can add a lot of cool things with other firebase plugins.

See more at https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/master/FlutterFire.md